# Breeze not returning full data model

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

Using Breeze with Entity Framework code first to return data from calls to a web service.

I have a data model that's several levels deep. In this instance I'm returning a "schedule" object, which has a number of child "DefaultItems", each one of which has a cost and a single "type" child with its own properties.

If you call the web service for one of these directly, you get something like this, which is as expected:

```
{
   $id:"1",
   $type:"Schedule_06B188AC55B213FE4B13EA5B77D9C039007E80E9DB6F6841C055777A028C5F95, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Core",
   DefaultItems:[
      {
         $id:"2",
         $type:"DefaultItem, Core",
         RowId:"d422af5d-d6ca-46a3-a142-1feb93348e1d",
         Cost:1,
         Type:{
            $id:"3",
            $type:"Type, Core",
            RowId:"38ed6d1b-d0b7-43cb-b958-2b2424b97759",
            Type:"Type1"
         },
         Schedule:{
            $ref:"1"
         }
      },
      //more DefaultItem objects
      {},
      {}
   ],
   RowId:"627eb2f2-ec74-4646-b3d1-d6423f84a2cd",
   Start:"2010-01-18T00:00:00.000",
   End:"2019-01-18T00:00:00.000"
}
```

This then comes down to the browser, where knockout is used to bind it to data objects. The trouble is that at this point, the data only seems to be one level deep.

So I can get at Schedule.Start and Schedule.End without issue. I can also iterate through the DefaultItem objects inside my Schedule and get their Costs out. But the Type objects inside DefaultItem just aren't there.

It's not about using an incorrect name to bind them: if you pause in the browser debugger and drill down into the JSON that the browser has, there's no Type objects at all, not even empty objects where they should be.

How come they come out of the web service, but don't seem to be in the data that Breeze passes back to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in Breeze, relationships have to be defined both ways in order to propagate. So I had to ensure that my the primary key in my Type class was marked as a foreign key to the DefaultItem class.

I believe this is currently registered as a bug. It's certainly a bit annoying.

Comment: We haven't seen this issue and I don't know of a bug in this area, so please send us a repro if you get the chance at breeze@ideablade.com. thx.

Comment: There's not an easy repro - but will send the details as requested.